# Excepción HRESULT: 0x800A01B6

Tags: vb.net

En la aplicación que estoy haciendo abro diferentes paginas web y obtengo cierta información del sitio. Hasta ahora no he tenido ningún problema. Le paso un array con las direcciones de las paginas que quiero obtener la información.

Al pasar la primera página no me da error pero cuando pasa en la segunda página me aparece el siguiente error:

> No se controló NotSupportedException Excepción de HRESULT:0x800A01B6

¿Alguien sabe porque puede pasar?

Os adjunto el código

```vb
Sub ParsearWeb(ByRef icInformacionCine As InformacionCines)
        Dim iContPeliculas As Integer
        'Dim iContFormatos As Integer
        Dim iContHorarios As Integer
        iContPeliculas = 0
        iContHorarios = 0
        Dim iContador = 2
        Dim ienlaces = 0
        Dim objIE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium
        Dim strTitulo As String = ""
        Dim arrEnlaces() As String = Nothing
        Dim strTipo As String = ""
        Dim strfecha = ""
        Dim strDia
        Dim strMes
        Dim strAnio
        Dim fecha As Date = Now
        'Dim arrHorarios() As String
        'Dim iCount As Integer
        objIE.Visible = True
        objIE.Navigate(icInformacionCine.strURLCartelera)
        WaitIEField(objIE, 0, "cartelera")
        For Each div In objIE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
            If div.hasAttribute("id") Then
                If div.id = "cartelera" Then
                    For Each enlace In div.GetElementsByTagName("a")
                        If enlace.HasAttribute("href") Then
                            ReDim Preserve arrEnlaces(0 To ienlaces)
                            Dim strParteEnlace = enlace.getAttribute("href").ToString()
                            'Obtenemos la posición del último / de la cadena
                            Dim posicion As Integer
                            posicion = InStrRev(icInformacionCine.strURLCartelera, "/")
                            Dim nuevoLink = Mid(icInformacionCine.strURLCartelera, 1, posicion) + strParteEnlace
                            arrEnlaces(ienlaces) = nuevoLink.ToString
                            ienlaces = ienlaces + 1
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            End If
        Next
        'objIE.Quit()
        'objIE = Nothing
        For Each nuevoenlace In arrEnlaces
            Dim objIE2 As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium
            objIE2.Visible = True

            objIE2.Navigate(nuevoenlace.ToString)
            'WaitIEField(objIE, 0, "efectotexto")
            Thread.Sleep(5000)
            objIE2.Stop()
            'Para obtener la fecha 
            For Each div In objIE2.Document.getElementsByTagName("div")
                If div.hasAttribute("id") Then
                    If div.id = "titulopelicula" Then
                        strTitulo = div.innertext
                    End If
                    If div.id = "barraotrodia" Then
                        For Each div3 In div.getElementsByTagName("div")
                            If div3.hasAttribute("id") Then
                                If div3.id = "formatodia" Then
                                    Dim strTempFecha = div3.innerText
                                    If strTempFecha = "HOY" Then
                                        strDia = Day(fecha).ToString
                                        strMes = Month(fecha).ToString
                                        strAnio = Year(fecha).ToString
                                        strfecha = strAnio + "-" + strMes + "-" + strDia
                                        'MsgBox(strfecha)
                                    ElseIf strTempFecha = "MAÑANA" Then
                                        fecha = (DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, fecha))
                                        strDia = Day(fecha).ToString
                                        strMes = Month(fecha).ToString
                                        strAnio = Year(fecha).ToString
                                        strfecha = strAnio + "-" + strMes + "-" + strDia
                                        'MsgBox(strfecha)
                                    Else
                                        Dim arrTemp = Split(Trim(strTempFecha), "/")
                                        strfecha = arrTemp(2) + "-" + arrTemp(1) + "-" + arrTemp(0)
                                        'MsgBox(strfecha)
                                    End If
                                    ReDim Preserve icInformacionCine.ipPeliculas(0 To iContPeliculas)
                                    icInformacionCine.ipPeliculas(iContPeliculas).strFecha = strfecha
                                    icInformacionCine.ipPeliculas(iContPeliculas).strTitulo = strTitulo
                                End If

                                If div3.id = "posicionhoras" Then
                                    'MsgBox(div3.innertext)
                                    ReDim Preserve icInformacionCine.ipPeliculas(iContPeliculas).arrFormatos(0 To iContHorarios)
                                    icInformacionCine.ipPeliculas(iContPeliculas).arrFormatos(iContHorarios).strTipo = "Normal"
                                    icInformacionCine.ipPeliculas(iContPeliculas).arrFormatos(iContHorarios).strHorario = div3.innertext
                                    iContHorarios = iContHorarios + 1
                                End If
                            End If

                        Next
                        iContPeliculas = iContPeliculas + 1
                        iContHorarios = 0
                    End If
                End If

            Next
            objIE2.Quit()

        Next
        objIE.Quit()
        objIE = Nothing
        'Next
        Exit Sub
```

El stackTrace indica lo siguiente:

> en Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LateBinding.LateGet(Object
>   o, Type objType, String name, Object[] args, String[] paramnames,
>   Boolean[] CopyBack) en
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object
>   Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[]
>   ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)
>
> en EBInformationParser.ALANDALUS.ParsearWeb(InformacionCines&
>   icInformacionCine) en
>   C:\XXXX\WEBInformationParser\WEBInformationParser\xxxx.vb:línea 57 en
>   WEBInformationParser.MainModule.Main()  en
>   C:\xxxx\WEBInformationParser\WEBInformationParser\MainModule.vb:línea
>   48 en System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[]
>   args) en
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly() en
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) en
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: El stack trace indica que el error sucedió en la línea 57 del archivo *C:\XXXX\WEBInformationParser\WEBInformationParser\xxxx.vb* (que obviamente le cambiastes el nombre). ¿Puedes indicarnos cual sentencia se encuentra en la línea 57?

Comment: La sentencia que se encuentra en esa linea es la siguiente: 
`For Each div In objIE2.Document.getElementsByTagName("div")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He logrado "arreglarlo" dejando más tiempo de ejecución para la carga de la nueva página que se abre. Esperando a que se cargue la etiqueta de donde obtengo los datos y ya no da el error. La pega es que en recorrer todas las páginas tarda un buen rato